# Multiple realm for multiple objects in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, realm

We have number of objects in our iOS app with close references to each other to nested levels. Our app is heavily multi-threaded. With realm(Objective C) as database choice,  following questions have come up and looking forward to answers:

1. Should we go with single realm or multiple realm, one for each object?
2. Do we need to bother about low memory issue, for both single/multiple approaches? Please note we have thousands of objects to deal with and will be using realm persisted on disk.
3. Do we need to be worried about growing realm size with thousands of objects? If we go with multiple realm, will it work for chained queries from  multiple realms?
4. Any best practices/constraints to consider for accessing objects from multiple realms? How to handle multi threading with multiple realm files? Does it need special treatment than multi threading with single realm?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should use one Realm. A Realm is a file with a bunch on objects and relations. It's not possible to query across multiple Realms. So only split up in multiple Realms if your objects are not related at all and you don't have relations to objects in other Realms.
Thousands of objects is no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks bmunk for quick response. Will  not it lead to low memory issues on iOS devices with a single realm file storing bunch of objects, each object type having thousands of instances? Are there any size limitations with realm with large data, persisted on disk?

Comment: It really depends on the size of each object obviously. Realm will memory map the entire file and roughly speaking only the objects you "touch" will be loaded into memory. There are some device specific limits, but it also depends on how fragmented your memory is. But in general there should not be problems even with a few hundred MB. So I suggest you make your own tests on low end devices.